# Testing classes implementing java.lang.Serializable to make sure any changes are backwards compaitible

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, serialization, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to use [OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) and [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) as to persist a simple String -> Foo database.

Foo may evolve over time, I'm wondering what testing strategies people have adopted to ensure that any older version of Foo persisted will be loadable going forward.

I was thinking of starting serialVersionUID at 1 for each specific class, storing each particular serialized version in a file I check in and have a test, which ensures I can read all of those files back and the values are what I expected.

It seems a little manual though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could automate the process of creating the serialized files

1. Store each version of Foo.java under `src/test/resources`
2. The test case could compile the `.java` to a `.class` at runtime using the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)
3. Use a disposable ClassLoader to load each `.class` version
4. Instantiate / populate (possibly using reflection) / serialize an instance

Once this is in place, the only maintenance wil be

1. The source files for each version
2. A population strategy